# PlayFramework. Use transaction in entity constructor

Tags: database, jpa, constructor, playframework, dao

I am trying to get list of entities in other entity constructor.

Unfortunately it fails on runtime.

Here is constructor:

```
public Contract_Answer() {
    this.commonEntities = CommonEntityDao.getList();
}
```

here is my whole stack trace:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: defaultPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:148) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:110) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:200) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:110) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:102) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1361) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: defaultPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:57) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.jar:1.0.1.Final]
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.jar:1.0.1.Final]
        at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.onStart(JPAPlugin.java:35) ~[play-java-jpa_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:88) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:87) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:139) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
        at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:385) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1742) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objectmyInsurance.models.part.Contract_Answer
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.instantiate(UnsavedValueFactory.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.getUnsavedIdentifierValue(UnsavedValueFactory.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildIdentifierProperty(PropertyFactory.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:507) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor317.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:163) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.instantiate(UnsavedValueFactory.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No EntityManager bound to this thread. Try wrapping this call in JPA.withTransaction, or ensure that the HTTP context is setup on this thread.
        at play.db.jpa.JPA.em(JPA.java:55) ~[play-java-jpa_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at generic.models.GenericDictionary.getList(GenericDictionary.java:38) ~[na:na]
        at myInsurance.models.part.Contract_Answer.<init>(Contract_Answer.java:49) ~[na:na]
        ... 47 common frames omitted
```

Please give me Your help. What Am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT

---

Thanks to instruction given by [@Mon Calamari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2145368/mon-calamari), I've rewritten my constructor. Unfortunatelly this code construction is new for me, and I can't manage it to work.

Here is new constructor:

```
public Contract_Answer() {
    List<CommonEntity> list = JPA.withTransaction(
            new F.Function0<List<CommonEntity>>() { 
                return CommonEntityDao.getList();
            }
    );
    // doing something with list variable
}
```

It doesn't compile:

```
Contract_Answer.java:60: error: illegal start of type
[error]                 return CommonEntityDao.getList();
Contract_Answer.java:60: error: ';' expected
[error]                 return CommonEntityDao.getList();
Contract_Answer.java:60: error: illegal start of type
[error]                 return CommonEntityDao.getList();
```

---

EDIT2

---

And Finally I make it compile as follow:

```
public Contract_Answer() {


    List<Contract_PolicyHolderHealthFormQuestion> list = new LinkedList<Contract_PolicyHolderHealthFormQuestion>();
    try {
        list = JPA.withTransaction(
            new play.libs.F.Function0<List<Contract_PolicyHolderHealthFormQuestion>>() {
                @Override
                public List<Contract_PolicyHolderHealthFormQuestion> apply() throws Throwable {
                    return new Contract_PolicyHolderHealthFormQuestion().getList();
                }
            }
        );
    } catch (Throwable e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(Contract_PolicyHolderHealthFormQuestion e: list) {
        Contract_PolicyHolderHealthFormAnswer ca = new Contract_PolicyHolderHealthFormAnswer();
        ca.question = e;
        this.answers.add(ca);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, `@Transactional` works only with action methods - not in a constructor. Use `JPA.withTransaction` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it with `withTransaction`

```
public Contract_Answer() {
    this.commonEntities = JPA.withTransaction(new F.Function0<List<CommonEntity>> () { 
        return CommonEntityDao.getList();
    });
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this compiles, posted it with no IDE support.

Comment: I've followed Yours instruction. Unfortunately it doesn't compile. Check my updated post for more details. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

answer is simple. You don't have any entity manager attached to this thread. 
There is a lot of solution:

- the easiest is to add to your method where you execute this code annotation @Transactional
- start your transaction manually:

  EntityManager em = JPA.em();
  JPA.bindForCurrentThread(em);

  but if you decide to do this manually you have to be carefoul and commit this transaction by your own. Decision is up to you :)